# Puppet Master in VIrtual Machine with Port Forwarding (SSL certificate error?)

Tags: networking, ssh, puppet

I am trying to run a puppet master on a virtual machine, and connect from a client machine, via port forwarding on the virtual machine's host.

**The details**

I have a virtual machine running Ubunto with Puppet 3.1.1 (called **mgt**). The host for the virtual machine (called **loki**) runs rinetd which forward incoming connections on port 8140 to the virtual machine.

I have a client machine (called **thor**) with Puppet 3.0.2.

Testing with netcat and telnet confirms that the port forwarding works and that I can connect from my client machine (**thor**) to the puppet master virtual machine (**mgt**).

When I run the puppet master (on **mgt**) with the following command it appears to start correctly:

```
puppet master --no-daemonize --debug
```

When I then run the agent (on **thor**), with the following command:

```
puppet agent --server loki --test --no-daemonize
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [self signed certificate in certificate chain for /CN=Puppet CA: localhost]
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/var/puppet/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [self signed certificate in certificate chain for /CN=Puppet CA: localhost]
Error: /File[/var/puppet/lib]: Could not evaluate: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [self signed certificate in certificate chain for /CN=Puppet CA: localhost] Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://loki/plugins: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [self signed certificate in certificate chain for /CN=Puppet CA: localhost]
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [self signed certificate in certificate chain for /CN=Puppet CA: localhost]
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [self signed certificate in certificate chain for /CN=Puppet CA: localhost]
```

But I get no additional output on the puppet master indicating that a connection was attempted or refused.

My understanding is that the puppet master should refuse to connect until the client's certificate is signed. Using the command **puppet set list** does not list any unsigned certificates.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to [sf]. Please do not tag questions with "SOLVED" or place answers in the question. Instead, post your own answer as an Answer below, and mark them solved by clicking the outline of the tick mark so that it turns green.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies, I misread your original error, it seems the master/agent have gotten confused, see [this link](http://bitcube.co.uk/content/puppet-errors-explained) for details.

Specifically:

> The server certificate that puppet has and the one that the puppetmaster is using differ. On a pure puppet node one simple way is just to remove the current SSL information and start again:
>
> find /var/lib/puppet -type f -print0 |xargs -0r rm
>
> Also ensure that the client and server agree what the current time is (otherwise the certificate created may not be valid on the other machine).

Comment: Many thanks for the quick answer. As you explained, removing all the files in both the agent's and master's SSL directories resulted in a certificate request to the master, which I was able to sign with **puppet master --sign name**. I'm now stuck with another problem reported by the agent: **hostname does not match the server certificate**, which I'm still diagnosing. This is probably caused by the proxy over the host of the virtual machine. Ill post more answers/questions as I determine what's going on.

Comment: **SOLVED:** The non-matching host name was caused by the port forwarding into the virtual machine. On the agent side, when starting puppet agent, I was using the parameter **--server loki** (which gets forwarded to the VM in loki), but the server's name and consequently its certname was the VM's hostname, which is **mgt**. This was a mismatch and caused the error I saw. The solution was to use, when starting puppet master, on the VM mgt, the extra parameter **--certname loki**. These master/agent command line parameters will now be migrated into the puppet.conf files on various machines.

Answer (score 0):

The following link gives a very good explanation of how Puppet certificates work:

- **http://www.masterzen.fr/2010/11/14/puppet-ssl-explained**